# Breaking out a closure to explain it to the unitiated

Tags: javascript, closures

I've got this, and it works:

```
myObject.myFunction = (function() {
    var closure = 0;

    return function(value) {
        if (arguments.length) {
            closure = value;
        } else {
            return closure;
        }
    }
})();
```

It acts as both a getter and a setter, so that calling myFunction(3.14) will set the closure and calling myFunction() will get the closure's value.

Q: Can I separate it out into a more wordy example (without being ridiculous)?  What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
myObject.myFunction1 = myFunction2;
myObject.myFunction1();

function myFunction2() {
    var closure = 0;

    return function(value) {
        if (arguments.length) {
            closure = value;
        } else {
            return closure;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm just trying to break down JavaScript into as small a chunks as possible so that my students can concentrate.

Edit 1:

Oh wait: I don't need myFunction2 at all.

Comment: I can't quite grasp what the actual question here is.

Comment: Yeah, I have problem with that.

Comment: In my proposed solution, when I call myObject.myFunction1(), it returns a function.  So really I should say myFunction3 = myObject.myFunction1()

Comment: Do you mean `myObject.myFunction1 = myFunction2();`? That should work.

Comment: @Phillip I now regret having voted to close your question. Voted to reopen, and also added a second part to my answer, that hopefully will help you more than the first part.

Comment: Oh!  Thanks @bfavaretto! Yeah, I keep coming back to SO because it's the best place in the world to get answers.  I'll reread your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you just looking for the simplest way to explain closures like:

```
function closure() {
    var privateData = "I'm hidden!";

    return {
        get: function () {
            return privateData;
        },
        set: function (arg) {
            privateData = arg;
        }
    };
}

var privateDataAccess = closure();

console.log(typeof (privateData)); // logs undefined -- privateData is out of scope
console.log(privateDataAccess.get()); // logs "I'm hidden!"
privateDataAccess.set("Now you changed me!");
console.log(privateDataAccess.get()); // logs "Now you changed me!"
```

That is probably as simple as it gets I think :-)

Comment: Well, I just don't like the syntax of a get and set.  I think I've decided on using the jQuery type of syntax where not passing in a parameter implies that it's a getter and passing in a parameter implies that it's a setter.

Comment: Yeah, I get you. The jQuery method makes the user side of the API more easy to understand and easier to use. Maybe you can use this in conjunction with your example as a simple of example of what goes on on the __other__ side of an API (behind the curtains).

Answer (score 1):

In your first example you are assigning the inner function to the property "myFunction".

In you second example you are assigning the outer function to the property "myfunction2".

This results in different behavior since the first example uses an immediately invoked function expression, where as the second example assigns a declared function named "myFunction2" to "myFunction1". In order to invoke the inner function you would actually have to do something like this.

```
myObject.myFunction1 = myFunction2;
var myFunction3 = myObject.myFunction1();
myFunction3();
```

or

```
myObject.myFunction1 = myFunction2();
myObject.myFunction1();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, `myObject.myFunction1 = myFunction2();` should work.

However, I really don't see any advantages from using that pattern for a simple getter and setter. You "closure" variable is only accessible from inside the getter/setter, and the function does nothing more than simply setting its value (without transforming it). I mean, the same could be accomplished with a regular property directly on your object, rather than a function.

---

Now I'm paying more attention to the fact that you're looking for a better way to explain closures. You could use meaningful, accurate names for your variables and functions, and add comments. Here is one suggestion, based on your code:

```
function createClosure() {
    // Only the function returned below can see the secret
    var secret = 0;
    return function(value) {
        // If anything was passed, change secret (returns undefined)
        if (arguments.length) {
            secret = value;
        // Nothing was passed, return secret
        } else {
            return secret;
        }

    }
}

// Create a function that enables access to the secret
var closure = createClosure();

// Use it to read the secret
console.log('the closure holds the secret: ' + closure());

// Use it to change the secret
closure(10);

// Read it again to check
console.log('the secret now holds ' + closure());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what I'm looking for:

```
function ConjunctionJunction() {
    var myClosure = 0;

    return function(myValue) {
        if (arguments.length) {
            myClosure = myValue;
        } else {
            return myClosure;
        }
    }
};
myObject = new Object();
myObject.myFunction = ConjunctionJunction(); // This creates a function and assigns it to the variable myObject.myFunction
myObject.myFunction(3.14); // This calls the newly created function as a setter
var x = myObject.myFunction(); // This calls it as a getter, which returns a value.
log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, wait. I think this is what I'm looking for.  This might really be it:

```
myObject = new Object();

;(function($, window, undefined) {
    var Variables = {};

    myObject.myFunction = function(argValue) {
        if (arguments.length) {
            Variables.myValue = argValue;
        } else {
            return Variables.myValue;
        }
    }
})(jQuery, window);


myObject.myFunction(3.14);
var x = myObject.myFunction();
log(x);
```

Comment: I thought you were trying to simplify your example syntactically to focus on closures?